# Laravel 6 translation into ajax response with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Trying to translate an ajax response with Laravel, but getting just the var as a string:

This is the response I have:

```
return "{{ __('data.color') }}";
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
data.color
```

The expected result should to be "red".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use simply

```
//...
$model->attribute = __('data.color');
//...
```

See [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#retrieving-translation-strings)

Comment: No, I'm using it to fill a datatables, so I need just the string.